# Rewrite code to make it faster

Tags: matrix, replacement

I got a problem and have to rewrite the following code and try to make it fast. Does someone have any idea how to solve it?

```
Total@Flatten@MatrixPower[Partition[270^5*Range[270^2],270],12]
```

Comment: Can you use machine-precision results? If you can, `Total@Flatten@MatrixPower[N@Partition[270^5*Range[270^2], 270], 12]` (notice the `N@`) evaluates instantly.

Comment: I think there are still a lot of speedups available, but for one, if you can't use `N`, I was able to cut the time to about 60% on my machine by factoring out the `270^5`: `((270^5)^12)*Total@Flatten@MatrixPower[Partition[Range[270^2],270],12]`

Comment: Do you need to do this computation multiple times? And do you need to vary parameters each time, e.g. change `270` to something else? I'm wondering if it would help to find a way to compute it just once in the context of whatever code is enclosing it, but the feasibility of this depends on which parameters need to vary each time your code computes it.

Answer (score 8):

There seems to be a pattern between the size of input matrix (`m`) and the sum of elements in `MatrixPower[m, 12]` that can be discovered cheaply using `FindSequenceFunction` on a short list of small sizes:

```
(list = With[{mm = ArrayReshape[Range[#^2], {#, #}]}, 
        Total[MatrixPower[mm, 12], 2]] & /@ Range[40];) // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
>  0.11
> ```

```
ClearAll[seqF]
(seqF[k_] := Evaluate @ FindSequenceFunction[list, k])//RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.0040
> ```

```
seqF[k]
```

[image]

`seqF[270]` evaluates almost instantly:

```
(270^5)^12 seqF[270] // RepeatedTiming
```

[image]

Compare with

```
Total @ Flatten @ MatrixPower[Partition[270^5*Range[270^2], 270], 12] // 
 RepeatedTiming
```

[image]